# Why doesn't the alias template in function parameter match the nested type it refers to?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-bug, template-aliases

This code compiles

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    struct Inner {} inner;
    void foo(Inner in);
};

template<typename T>
void A<T>::foo(typename A<T>::Inner in) {

}

int main() {
    A<int> a;
    a.foo(a.inner);
}
```

And it won't if I change `typename A<T>::Inner` to an alias template like

```
template<typename T>
using AInner = typename A<T>::Inner;

template<typename T>
void A<T>::foo(AInner<T> bar) {

}
```

The compiler complains that `error: no declaration matches ‘void A<T>::foo(AInner<T>)’`

I'm not quite familiar with the rules of alias templates. Aren't they the same type?

---

Edit:
Here is the full demo:

// hello.cpp

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    struct Inner {} inner;
    void foo(Inner in);
};

template<typename T>
using AInner = typename A<T>::Inner;

template<typename T>
void A<T>::foo(AInner<T> in) {

}

int main() {
    A<int> a;
    a.foo(a.inner);
}
```

And I compile it with `g++ (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0`

The output:

```
hello.cpp:11:6: error: no declaration matches ‘void A<T>::foo(AInner<T>)’
   11 | void A<T>::foo(AInner<T> in) {
      |      ^~~~
hello.cpp:4:10: note: candidate is: ‘void A<T>::foo(A<T>::Inner)’
    4 |     void foo(Inner in);
      |          ^~~
hello.cpp:2:8: note: ‘struct A<T>’ defined here
    2 | struct A {
      |
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the *full* and *complete* build log. There might be informational notes that includes hints about the problem.

Comment: clang++  10.0.0-4ubuntu1 compiles both

Comment: Congratulations, you seem to have found a bug in GCC. :) I recommend you try [the compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org) to test with newer versions to see if the bug has been fixed. If not then please report it to GCC so it can be fixed.

Comment: omg I can't believe it @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: You could of course just write `void A<T>::foo(Inner in)`; once you’ve named the function you’re inside the class for name-lookup purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. This is a known bug of g++, see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=101789

Other compilers are fine with this code, online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5Pv9KW8vj